# Sinatra external IP

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to work out how to find the IP address that I can give to someone so that they can connect to my Sinatra server. I've tried just looking up my IP on Google and using that, but apparently no dice. Basically, what I need is an IP address that someone can type into their address bar and connect to my Sinatra server.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: This is less of a sinatra question and more of a networking/systems configuration question.   You need to configure your router to use port forwarding and open port 4567 on your firewall.
A better option would be to skip all that entirely and put your app on heroku instead

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/5/32_deploy_merb_sinatra_or_any_rack_app_to_heroku/

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel#readme

It's a gem that allows you to share localhost.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsonip.com/ or http://www.whatismyip.com/ will do the trick.

You can look into Dynamic DNS if you'd like to have a domain name that always points at your current IP.

Comment: Oh it was just a matter of port forwarding. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

[ipecho](http://ipecho.net/plain) will give you your external IP address. To get it from `Ruby`, simply use `net/http`:

```
require 'net/http'
myIP = Net::HTTP.get('ipecho.net', '/plain')
```